# Running Python code from Notepad++ doesn't generate .txt files

Tags: python, notepad++

So currently I'm practicing Python and I have this line of code:

```
print(f"{someList}", file=open("generatedList.txt", "w"))
```

When I tried to run it on Notepad++ using a run command of `python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`, it <del>doesn't</del> generate**s** the .txt file **but in the Notepad++ folder**. When I tried to run exactly the same code to the IDLE it generates the .txt file on the working folder.

Why is that? Should I change something to the run command? I prefer Notepad++ as a text editor.

Btw, I'm using **Python 3.8.5**

Comment: It generates the text file *in the current directory*. And the current directory for your Notepad++ process is not the directory of the currently edited file. Look at the properties of the shortcut that started Notepad++. The "Start in:" field determines the path Notepad++ will use as the current directory.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for your response! I did try searching the filename(`generatedList.txt`) using [Everything.exe](https://www.voidtools.com) but the file really doesn't exist anywhere unless I run it using IDLE. I also double-checked it just right now, no `generatedList.txt` were found on the directory of  Notepad++.

Comment: Good idea with Everything.exe! :) Look at the "Start in:" value anyway, because it's likely that you don't have write permissions to that directory. Typically it defaults to the program's installation directory, and that's write-protected for normal users. Change it to `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: Everything.exe saved me a lot of hassle :D You are right! The problem was the permission. I just edited the `Security` under Notepad++ folder properties and allowed `Full control` to the User. But how can I make it generate on the current folder where the .py file is saved?

Comment: NO DON'T DO THAT, change the permissions back. Modify the "Start in" value. I'm not a Notepad++ user but I would expect that there is a way to do set a directory before running a command.

Comment: Random Google hit https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17423/changing-default-directory/4. There's probably more than one way to do it, read a couple of them.

Comment: So I returned it back, and after reading "NO DON'T DO THAT", I realized that it could expose me to security vulnerabilities. So my "Start In:" is `"C:\Program Files\Notepad++"` and I modified it to my current working folder where I save my python scripts `D:\DOCUMENTS\Python` is this right? I tried running and it didn't generate the .txt file.

Comment: Yeah, potentially it's risky to modify file system permissions. Not particularly in this case, but resorting to "just modify file permissions" is a risky attitude, so this should be the last solution, after *everything else* has failed. You can use procmon.exe (from the Sysinternals suite) to monitor in real time where Python is trying to write the file. Also did you try the suggestions in the link I posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know if it is okay but I think I know now how to make it save on **wherever directory you want** I just experimented and tried it out.

from this code :

```
print(f"{flippedCoins}", file=open("generatedFlips.txt", "w"))
```

You'll just need to add the directory where would like to save it!

```
print(f"{flippedCoins}", file=open("C:\The\Directory\You\Want\to\Save\it\generatedFlips.txt", "w"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `__file__` variable to retrieve the location of the script, and use that to construct an absolute path for your output file:

```py
import os.path

SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
FILE_PATH = os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, "generatedList.txt")
...
with open(FILE_PATH, "w") as fh:
    print(f"{someList}", file=fh)
```

If you prefer to work with local file paths, you could change the working directory to the one where you want to dump the file:

```py
import os
os.chdir("c:/path/to/some/directory")
```

If you can't locate the output file when launching the script from and IDE and want to figure out what the script's working directory is, you can print it:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You can always provide an absolute path to the file, wherever the script is executed from:

```py
with open("c:/path/to/some/file.txt", "w") as fh:
    print(f"{someList}", file=fh)
```

Comment: I will consider this! Thank you!

Comment: Or with the newer [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). `full_file_name = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'generatedList.txt')`